# Hypothesis testing against LFR benchmark

Tags: hypothesis-testing, networks

I have collected data for my project and generated a network out of it. I have done my dose of analysis of the network (power law exponent, nr of communities etc.). I'm wondering whether certain features of my network (fx. degree assortativity or a nr of articulation points) are rather standard for a network with characteristics I derived from the analysis or are they are more extraordinary. For that I am using LFR method of graph generation by passing appropriate parameters derived from my original graph to a NetworkX LFR_benchmark_graph method. For now I want to test my original graph against 100 LFR-generated ones.

My question is: what kind of hypothesis testing is appropriate for this use case? My first idea was one-sample Wilcoxon test as I will be comparing a fx. single value of degree assortativity against an array of 100 entries of degree assortativities. I would love to hear others opinion on that and whether this approach is correct or there exists a more appropriate method.